# How to recognize an illegal output in a crossword puzzle?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to get the program to recognize an illegal output in a crossword puzzle both horizontally and vertically. So far my program can print the words in the crossword horizontally and vertically, but it also adds in words that are illegal outputs to the crossword puzzle. I'm trying to get the program to place the illegal outputs somewhere else, and then if it can't be placed somewhere else, skip it. An example of illegal outputs is shown below.

My Output: The word "prove" added horizontally would be an illegal output because it creates the words "dr", "do", "lv", and "ee", and "no" added vertically  would be illegal outputs because it creates the extra word "no" horizontally

```
            a d d l e               
            p r o v e               
            p                       
            r                       
        c l o w n i n g             
            v     n o               
            e     c
                  l
                  i
                  n
                  e
```

My code:

```
def printboard(board):
print('--------------------')
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board)):
        print(board[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
print('--------------------')
blank= ' '
board = [[blank]*20 for i in range(20)]

def firstword(board, word):
D = len(board)
n = len(word)
if n > D:
    return False
else:
    for k in range(n):
        column = D//2-n//2+k
        board[D//2][column] = word[k]
    return True

def checkVertical(board, word, row, col):
D = len(board)
n = len(word)
blank = ' '
if n>(20-row):
    return False
matchesoneletter = False
for k in range(n):
    wordletter = word[k]
    boardletter = board[row + k][col]
    if wordletter == boardletter:
        matchesoneletter = True
    if boardletter == blank:
        continue
    elif boardletter != wordletter:
        return False
return matchesoneletter


def addVertical(board, word):
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board)):
        if checkVertical(board, word, i, j):
            for k in range(len(word)):
                board[i + k][j] = word[k]
            return True 
return False

def checkhorizontal(board, word, row, col):
D = len(board)
n = len(word)
blank = ' '
if n >(20-col):
    return False
matchesoneletter = False
for k in range(n):
    wordletter = word[k]
    boardletter = board[row][col+k]
    if wordletter == boardletter:
        for a in range(n):
            new_col = col + k
        matchesoneletter = True
    if boardletter == blank:
        continue
    elif boardletter != wordletter:
        return False
return matchesoneletter

def addHorizontal(board, word) :
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board)):
        if checkhorizontal(board, word, i, j):
            for k in range(len(word)):
                board[i][j+k] = word[k]
            return True 
return False

firstword(board, "clowning")
addVertical(board, "approve")
addHorizontal(board, "addle")
addHorizontal(board, "prove")
printboard(board)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't execute. Please make sure to format it properly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: I added the "algorithm" tag: as @Brian says, this is a non-trivial problem, but within the grasp of existing algorithms.  With that identification, I strongly suggest that you complete the research we expect of someone posting an algorithm question: do the on-line search for algorithms in crossword placement.  This is a human skill dating back to the early days of puzzle construction, and there is enough literature on the topic that you should be able to find something useful.

Comment: I searched up the algorithm but it's in java, a language I'm not familiar with. Also, I was asking on how to place words that are illegal outputs elsewhere in the grid or skip it if it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a trivial problem, let alone a problem easy enough to explain over stackoverflow easily. However, I happened to do the same thing for a scrabble AI agent back in college. We used about 3 methods to validate the placement of words. You basically have to look at every row/column around the newly placed word and validate those using a `word_validation` lookup dict or something.

Here's the [method](https://github.com/FermenFlo/Scrabble-Solver/blob/c16fc3ebbf36ac07c8f2e628b0bbbca17713e998/src/Scrabble.py#L182) in question. Feel free to poke around and steal any code you want. I will warn you that it's not very well documented as we were scrambling to finish.

EDIT: As per request in comments, here's the essential code from the link above in case it gets deleted. I'll warn you that it is already hard enough to understand with context, so if the link is valid when you're reading this, then I suggest following it.

```
    def validate_move(self, word, indices, agent_id, state): # this will need to take in game state

        agent = state.agents[agent_id]
        #Check if agent has required tiles to form a word
        required_tiles = Counter([word[i] for i, index in enumerate(indices) if word[i] != state.board[index]])

        for tile in required_tiles:
            if agent.tiles[tile] < required_tiles[tile]:
                return False

        # Check if all created words are valid
        created_words = self.get_created_word_indices(word, indices, agent_id = agent_id, state = state)
        # return created_words

        for (word, indices) in created_words:
                if not self.valid_word(word):
                    return False

        return True

    def get_created_word_indices(self, word, indices, agent_id, state):
        '''Returns the indices of all newly createds from placing a word in a position'''

        size = self.size
        new_board = state.place(word, indices, agent_id = agent_id, scrabble_rules = self, mock = True)
        hor_grids = [((x, max(indices, key = lambda x: x[1])[1]), [(x, y) for y in range(size)])
                     for x in set([i[0] for i in indices])]
        ver_grids = [((max(indices, key = lambda x: x[0])[0], y),  [(x, y) for x in range(size)])
                     for y in set([i[1] for i in indices])]

        # I am so sorry to whoever has to read this nested, nested, nested listcomp. Buet we needed to make this fast tho...
        affected_indices = [grid[min(ind for ind, board_ind  in enumerate(grid)
                                 if all([new_board[test_ind] for test_ind in grid[ind: grid.index(max_played_ind) + 1]])):
                                 max(ind for ind, board_ind  in enumerate(grid)
                                     if all([new_board[test_ind] for test_ind in grid[grid.index(max_played_ind): ind + 1]])) + 1]
                            for max_played_ind, grid in hor_grids + ver_grids]

        word_indices = [indices for indices in affected_indices if state.unplayed_indices(indices) if len(indices) > 1]
        return [(''.join([new_board[ind] for ind in indices]), indices) for indices in word_indices]

    def valid_word(self, word):
        return self.trie.has_key(word.upper())
```

Essentially, `validate_move` is the entry point for placing a move on the game board. `get_created_word_indices` gets called by `validate_move` to get a list of all valid words that are created by placing some arbitrary word. So that's the part you want to mimic it sounds like. `valid_word` is a simple lookup using an optimized data structure known as a trie. As I said, it's way too involved to explain fully over SO, but I hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24659968)

Comment: @jrook, that's fair. I contemplated posting the code, but decided not to since the code was so intertwined with other code, it would be nearly meaningless out of context. I'll add it for posterity's sake

Comment: Do you know how this would look without object oriented programming? I haven't learned that yet

Comment: @user12394062, this is going to be a pain to do in functional programming. But for the most of this specific task, you can either pass in values instead of accessing attributes (e.g. make `self.state` an argument to the function as `state` instead) or you can hard-code those values everywhere all-together.  And instead of accessing methods (`self.function(...)`) just access the functions directly (`function(...)`). And btw, you can ignore all the `scrabble_rules` and `agent` related stuff. That was for the AI aspect of the code.